# Authenticate AWS API Gateway Websocket backend calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

As I don't want to deal with websockets (how to handle scaling, reconnection, etc.), I have decided to use AWS API Gateway Websocket.

This works great so far, but how can I make sure, that calls to my real backend (HTTP(S)) are really from the API AWS Gateway? The documentation says to use SSL/Client certificates and to set them at a deployment stage. But in contrast to the REST API settings page, there is no option to choose a client certificate in the stage settings for a websocket api.

How can I make sure that calls to my HTTP backend are really from AWS?

Comment: What is the websocket endpoitn connected to? Lambda? EC2?

Comment: The websocket endpoint is HTTP Server (not hosted on AWS)

Comment: So what is the actual question? Adding authentication on the API gateway so that you have to authenticate before calling the server via the gateway?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.